# Books on the Riemannian geometry of four-manifolds

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, 4-manifolds

I am currently trying to read about Weyl tensors, Ricci curvature and Einstein manifolds, specifically on four-manifolds where there is a decomposition of the space of two-forms in a self-dual and anti-self-dual subspaces. I cannot seem to find any books at introductory level for these topics. I would appreciate any books, papers or lecture notes suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it would be viewed as an introductory level book, but the material you mentioned is discussed in Besse's *Einstein Manifolds*, chapter $1$, sections $G$ and $H$.

Also, you might be interested in chapter $6$, section $D$ which covers some necessary conditions for the existence of Einstein metrics on closed four-manifolds, namely the Hitchin-Thorpe inequality and Gromov's inequality.

Another excellent resource is LeBrun's paper [*Four-Dimensional Einstein Manifolds, and Beyond*](http://intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/sdg/2001/0006/0001/SDG-2001-0006-0001-a010.pdf).